# How do zombies win in Last Night on Earth: Timber Peak?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

My friends and I played Last Night on Earth extensively. Games were always very close, and tough for both sides. We liked it so much we got the Timber peak sequel/expansion.

However, we find now that the heroes are having a ridiculously easy time.
After about halfway through the game, the heroes become so powerful they are literally running into hoards of 5+ zombies, and killing every one without a wound.
I'm starting to think we are missing a trick or new rule, as I can't believe other people would consider what we've seen as balanced. The only buffs to the zombies are generally to fight cards, and only after they wound. Problem is, after a certain point, it becomes almost impossible to wound a hero.
Yet the heroes now get triple bandages, triple ammo, triple gasoline, police shotgun, very powerful upgrades like winning on ties and extra fight dice. The Ed Baker guy, who can take 4 wounds, and starts off with an upgrade, always becomes an unstoppable tank every game.
I once had 6 zombies on him, and I was only able to roll to see if I might win once, and needed a 6.. but if I had got a 6 he could have made me re-roll it..

Anyone got any tips/strategies for how zombies might win in Timber Peak?

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually own Timber Peak so I can't help you from experience but I did find the following comment from [this post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/917203/anyone-else-have-problem-humans-being-way-over-pow) on BGG relevant.

> I found that zombie tactics in TP are different from LNOE. Without going into detail, I'd say the zombies require a bit more subtlety than in the earlier game.

So to answer your question: If your gaming group is really use to vanilla LNoE they may need to adapt a different play style for Timber Peak.

The rest of the thread on the above link might also help answer your question.